# Site information icons in different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, favicon

I was wondering if the icons in the address bar, which are showing the site's information, are called favicons or does it depend on the browser?

For example in Safari the favicon is diplayed in the address bar:

[image]

But not in Chrome and Firefox:

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image]

So what would you call these icons in Chrome and Firefox?

And third, is there a way to change these icons or do they just come with the browser defaults, when visiting sites?

Answer (score 1):

The parts you've circled for Chrome and Firefox are not favicons, they are site information. The favicons for Chrome and Firefox are shown in the tab right at the top, with the title text next to them.

Favicons are decided upon by the site, not the browser. For instance, the favicon on this page can be viewed in the page source:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```